# How do Kirk and Chekov find the time to change uniforms in Star Trek Beyond

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond, star-trek-reboot

In *Star Trek Beyond*, when everyone abandons ship in the escape pods, Kirk and Chekov are in different uniforms when they land on the planet. Where did they find time to change uniforms and why did they change?

Comment: The answer is, of course, terrible writing and editing.

Comment: @Valorum Perhaps they were strippers before joining Star Fleet. The answer would then be strategically placed Velcro.

Comment: Because [Changing Clothes is a Free Action](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChangingClothesIsAFreeAction)?

Comment: I assumed those were ‘survival outfits’ that were in all pods. You likely wouldn’t know where your pod would land in an emergency so you would want something warm and protective.